# Android studio app crashes when closing image crop activity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-activity, firebase-storage

I use this library to crop images in Android studio: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

I can upload a photo and send it to my firebase storage but when I open the cropping tool and back out by pressing the back arrow the app crashes. The error is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: result must not be null

The error references to my code at " var uri = result.uri " at line 4

My code:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    var result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
    var uri = result.uri

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context?.contentResolver, uri)
        imageView12.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
    if (uri != null) {
        val ref = storageReference!!.child("" + UUID.randomUUID())
        ref.putFile(uri!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uriLink ->
                        currentUser.profileImage = uriLink.toString()
                        saveData()
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                }
                .addOnProgressListener { taskSnapshot ->
                    val progress = 100.0 * taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot
                            .totalByteCount
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + progress.toInt() + "%")
                }
    }

}
```

I start the crop activity with:

```
context?.let {
        CropImage.activity()
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(it, this)
    };
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey the library you've shared for cropping gives a proper explanation how to get data from `CropImage Activity` please have a look at that Readme again and you'll find your solution.

Comment: I did take a look at it and tried their code what do you think is the solution?

Comment: The **if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)**
should come above the line  **var result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)**

Answer (score 0):

`CropImage.getActivityResult(data)` [can return null](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/2a4a425668bfff1329dd5bfb1b80b0829bb4cc67/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/CropImage.java#L442) so you need to null check `result` before you try to access its `uri` property. You're null checking `uri` lower down, so if that can be null you could just do `var uri = result?.uri`

Slso make it a `val` if you can, it can save you a lot of headaches with handling something that can change, especially if it's nullable!